# Android Can we check Visibility of view in one activity

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a view is visible or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791607/how-can-i-check-if-a-view-is-visible-or-not-in-android)

We can setVisibility to `VISIBLE`, `GONE` and `INVISIBLE`.
However, can we check the Visibility in such activity so that we can know which view is gone or which view is visible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
you're looking for:

if (myImageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) 
{
    // Its visible
} 
else 
{
    // Either gone or invisible
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that using `yourView.getVisibility();` you could also use `isShown();`

One difference is that `isShown();` returns true if this view and all of its ancestors are `VISIBLE` and `getVisibility();` returns One of VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE.

Hope that helps.

[Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility%28%29).