# How can you tell if a View is visible on screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-view, android-scrollview, visible

I want to check if a `View` within a `ScrollView` is currently visible in Android. I am not checking if it is focused on yet but if it is currently being displayed on screen. Is there a method in `View` that can tell me if the view is currently visible?

Comment: Look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629167/614807

Answer (score 77):

This code works for me:

```
public static boolean isVisible(final View view) {
    if (view == null || !view.isShown()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Rect actualPosition = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition);
    final Rect screen = new Rect(0, 0, getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());
    return actualPosition.intersect(screen);
}
```

Comment: Note to get the screen width and height use: `Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels` and `Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels`

Comment: It's working like a charm, after context changes, in recyclerviews, in viewpagers, everywhere. Unbelievable!

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer. It works perfectly!

Comment: Really valuable answer, works good unlike getGlobalVisibleRect itself.

Comment: don't use "intersect" if you want to just check for intersection. Use "intersects" instead. Only use "intersect" if you would like to record intersection

Answer (score 23):

```
int[] location = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

or

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
```

Now use this location or rectangle to check if it is in your visible bounds or not. If it is simply the entire screen, check against `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`.

As pointed by Antek in the comments below, the view may still be gone or invisible with the returned values here telling where it was last drawn. So combining the above bounds-related condition with an `view.isShown()` or `view.getVisibility() == VISIBLE` should take care of that.

Comment: this does not work when toggling visibility - if your view was initially visible, then it will retain its visible rect dimensions.

Comment: You can sure add a check for view's visibility as well

Comment: what do you mean? The view has now `visibility = GONE` (I just toggled it, it had `visibility = VISIBLE`), yet the visible rectangle remains as it was when the view was created. No need to check it, as I set it myself in one place in code.

Comment: I meant depending on the intention, you can add the check for view.getVisibility() == VISIBLE along with the position returned on screen. For the question actually it would make sense to add it, I'll edit the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Antek It would be interesting to test this out if you're working around this - what happens when the view is drawn, then made GONE then never drawn again? I imagined GONE would update the location but if it doesn't it worth checking if we stay with a stale location going forward. Thanks!

Comment: changing the visibility to GONE doesn't change the location, actually - for my particular case it's `0,0` either way (fullscreen view group)

Comment: and actually I will just wait a bit (100 ms?) in background thread, because I noticed that I don't need to check explicitly for the view being drawn or not - the issue is (most probably) caused by calling this chunk of code many times in a second from another place.

Comment: 0,0! Either ways my edit holds for an invisible view :P

Comment: well, my understanding is that by `location` they meant upper-left corner of a view (which can have some dimensions) - so any view located there, regardless of size, will have such location.

Comment: yep... try getting the visible Rect instead in your case

Comment: do you mean `boundingBox`?

Answer (score 18):

[zegee29's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038086/6029532) answer is quite helping. Although I'd like to suggest using the result of `view.getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition)` too, because in some cases `Rect.intersects()` returns `true` when item is not visible at all, so the resulting code is:

```
fun View.isVisible(): Boolean {
    if (!isShown) {
        return false
    }
    val actualPosition = Rect()
    val isGlobalVisible = getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition)
    val screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val screen = Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
    return isGlobalVisible && Rect.intersects(actualPosition, screen)
}
```

Or you may just the result of `getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition)`

Comment: this is correct way  because in some cases Rect.intersects() returns true when item is not visible at all

Answer (score 2):

Java variant of [Диана Ганиева](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6029532)'s
[post](/a/66907184/2323972):

```java
boolean isViewOnScreen(View target)
{
    if (!target.isShown())
    {
        return false;
    }
    final var actualPosition = new Rect();
    final var isGlobalVisible = target.getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition);
    final var screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    final var screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    final var screen = new Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    return isGlobalVisible && Rect.intersects(actualPosition, screen);
}
```

Answer (score -12):

try

```
if(view.isShown()) {
    // Visible
} else { 
    // Invisible
}
```

Comment: This will be true if, for example, there is an overlay occluding the `View` so not reliable, nor the correct answer

Comment: This is incorrect. isShown() returns the visibility property of the View.

Comment: Why does this have several upvotes? It's wrong people!

Answer (score -22):

```
public boolean checkVisiblity(View view) {
    return view.isShown();
}
```

Answer (score -31):

The function View.getVisibility() can have below values:

- View.VISIBLE (0): the view is visible.
- View.INVISIBLE (1): The view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
- View.GONE (2): the view is gone. Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added

You can see below link for more info.
[How can I check if a view is visible or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791607/how-can-i-check-if-a-view-is-visible-or-not-in-android/3791698#3791698)

Comment: Why not give credit to the original answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3791698/562935

Comment: @tidbeck this answer is completely wrong! he wants to know view is visibile right now in screen or not! visibility attribute always return visible if you don't change it. this attribute is not related to scroll,it only modify by programmer.

Comment: By the way, constants for visible, invisible and gone are 0,4 and 8 respectively.