# How to know if a Fragment is Visible?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the support library v4 and my questions are, How to know if a Fragment is Visible? and How can I change the propierties of the Layout inflated in the Fragment?

I'm using fragments like in the android developers tutorial with a FragmentActivity.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible()

Comment: The solution that worked best for me was http://stackoverflow.com/a/6751537/1816603

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
MyFragmentClass test = (MyFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("testID");
if (test != null && test.isVisible()) {
     //DO STUFF
}
else {
    //Whatever
}
```

Comment: Actually it will be `test != null && test.isVisible()` otherwise when test is null it will throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Axxiss Thanks, I forgot about that, I had done these as two different if's in my code but just modified it for simplicity here. Come to think of it... I should probably go change that in my code...

Comment: You can do it by just `if (MyFragmentClass.this.isVisible())`.

Comment: What if we add some more fragments inside this fragment using `FragmentPagerAdapter` ?

Comment: using a tabLayout will return true for any tab adjacent to the current tab

Comment: In findFragmentByTag() , which tag have to define here ?

Comment: What if fragment is inside Tablayout? Please guide.

Answer (score 62):

Both `isVisible()` and `isAdded()` return `true` as soon as the `Fragment` is created, and not even actually visible. The only solution that actually works is:

```
if (isAdded() && isVisible() && getUserVisibleHint()) {
    // ... do your thing
}
```

This does the job. Period.

NOTICE:
getUserVisibleHint() is now deprecated. be careful.

Comment: I spend a lot of time just for this getUserVisibleHint() THX

Comment: yeah, lets bring it to top

Comment: I think this answer is the most correct solution. This would be accepted answer

Comment: isVisible check isAdded thus isAdded is redundant here

Comment: @Killer: true, but it doesn't always work in all situations unless we explicitly add isVisible()

Comment: isVisible comes after isAdded. So could you give a scenario where isAdded will not work as you are mentioning both isAdded and isVisible @Y.S.

Comment: @Sp4Rx: As I have mentioned in my answer, both isVisible() and isAdded() return true as soon as the Fragment is created, and not even actually visible.

Comment: My bad if I had miss interpreted. isVisible() says that _Return true if the fragment is currently visible to the user. This means it: (1) has been added, (2) has its view attached to the window, and (3) is not hidden_ and I also agree what @Killer has said in his comment that isAdded() is redundant when isVisible() is checked. So can we have `isVisible() && getUserVisibleHint()` ? @Y.S.

Comment: @Sp4Rx: You can try that, but I would advise you to test it thoroughly in all situations. My experience was that this is what works correctly all the time.

Comment: getUserVisibleHint() is now deprecated - what is the alternative?

Answer (score 48):

If you want to know when use is looking at the fragment you should use

```
yourFragment.isResumed()
```

instead of

```
yourFragment.isVisible()
```

First of all `isVisible()` already checks for `isAdded()` so no need for calling both. Second, non-of these two means that user is actually seeing your fragment. Only `isResumed()` makes sure that your fragment is in front of the user and user can interact with it if thats whats you are looking for.

Comment: Beautiful answer and explanation, +1 a million times if i could

Comment: This does'nt work. It gives me true for all tabs evn though only one of them is in use and visible.

Comment: It seems not working. isResumed still returns 'true', even the fragment is in back stack and not visible at all. I checked 'isResumed' on 'onPrepareOptionsMenu' method and I'm using getChildFragmentManager for child fragments in the view pager.

Comment: @leoOrion I have the same situation

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko the getUserVisibleHint() is what will tell you if its visible to user. isVisible() will return true even if the fragment is in backOfStack but not visible to user.

Comment: @leoOrion in my case each fragment returns `getUserVisibleHint()` is true, weird %(

Comment: If you are using ViewPager, you should note that ViewPager is implemented to initialize not only the visible fragment but also the ones that are immediate left and right of the current visible fragment. Those fragments are not in "backstack". They are fully resumed and visible in program's perspective, it is just that they are not visible on the screen.

Answer (score 19):

you can try this way:

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

or

```
Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

In this if, you check if currentFragment is  instance of YourFragment

```
if (currentFragment instanceof YourFragment) {
     Log.v(TAG, "your Fragment is Visible");
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can override setMenuVisibility like this:

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
   if (visible) {
      //Do your stuff here
   }

   super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's odd that a function with this name can give such functionality, i've been searching a lot about this problem, thank you so much.

Comment: This is correct for people using Tab Layout like WhatsApp. Thank you for the Answer.

Comment: This method is deprecated in AndroidX, which method needs to be used?

Comment: Thanks stranger, for saving my day!! Where can I donate you? 

Answer (score 11):

`getUserVisibleHint()` comes as true only when the fragment is on the view and visible

Comment: In my case each fragment returns `getUserVisibleHint()` is true

Comment: The possible case for this is fragments might be added to back stack with some solid colored background.So the most recent fragments hide the others on screen.

Comment: depreciated in API 29

Answer (score 9):

One thing to be aware of, is that `isVisible()` returns the visible state of the **current** fragment. There is a problem in the support library, where if you have nested fragments, and you hide the parent fragment (and therefore all the children), the child still says it is visible.

`isVisible()` is final, so can't override unfortunately. My workaround was to create a `BaseFragment` class that all my fragments extend, and then create a method like so:

```
public boolean getIsVisible()
{
    if (getParentFragment() != null && getParentFragment() instanceof BaseFragment)
    {
        return isVisible() && ((BaseFragment) getParentFragment()).getIsVisible();
    }
    else
    {
        return isVisible();
    }
}
```

I do `isVisible() && ((BaseFragment) getParentFragment()).getIsVisible();` because we want to return false if **any** of the parent fragments are hidden.

This seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you! Wasted 2 hours scratching my head over this.

Comment: What if the parent fragment is visible but the nested fragment for which one is checking is not visible?.. How do we check for such a scenario?

Answer (score 4):

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null && articleFrag.isVisible()) {

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
    }
```

see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 2):

Adding some information here that I experienced:

`fragment.isVisible` is only working (`true/false`) when you `replaceFragment()` otherwise if you work with `addFragment()`, `isVisible` always returns `true` whether the fragment is in behind of some other fragment.

Comment: Any solution to handle case where fragment is Added ? Need to know if fragment is visible in UI ?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you use a Fragment layout with a ViewPager (TabLayout), you can easily ask for the current (in front) fragment by ViewPager.getCurrentItem() method. It will give you the page index.

Mapping from page index to fragment[class] should be easy as you did the mapping in your FragmentPagerAdapter derived Adapter already.

```
int i = pager.getCurrentItem();
```

You may register for page change notifications by

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Of course you must implement *interface ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener*

```
public class MainActivity 
    extends AppCompatActivity
    implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{
    public void onPageSelected (int position)
    {
        // we get notified here when user scrolls/switches Fragment in ViewPager -- so
        // we know which one is in front.
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "current page " + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    public void onPageScrolled (int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int state) {
    }
}
```

My answer here might be a little off the question. But as a newbie to Android Apps I was just facing exactly this problem and did not find an answer anywhere. So worked out above solution and posting it here -- perhaps someone finds it useful.

Edit: You might combine this method with LiveData on which the fragments subscribe. Further on, if you give your Fragments a page index as constructor argument, you can make a simple amIvisible() function in your fragment class.

In MainActivity:

```
private final MutableLiveData<Integer> current_page_ld = new MutableLiveData<>();
public LiveData<Integer> getCurrentPageIdx() { return current_page_ld; }

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    current_page_ld.setValue(position);
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page: But only on first
        // creation -- not on restore state !!!
        // see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35677363/3290848
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return MyFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 1:
                return OtherFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 2:
                return XYFragment.newInstance(2);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In Fragment:

```
    public static MyFragment newInstance(int index) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("idx", index);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mPageIndex = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
        ...
    }
    
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        MyActivity mActivity = (MyActivity)context;

        mActivity.getCurrentPageIdx().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer data) {
                if (data == mPageIndex) {
                    // have focus
                } else {
                    // not in front
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using Android's BottomNavigationView and managing fragments with `FragmentTransactions.hide(frag)` and `FragmentTransaction.show(frag)`. So, to detect if a fragment is visible or not, I used following:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

    open fun onFragmentVisible(){
        
    }
    
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (!isHidden){
            onFragmentVisible()
        }
    }

    override fun onHiddenChanged(hidden: Boolean) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden)
        if (!hidden){
            onFragmentVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

You can extend BaseFragment in your fragment and implement it's `onFragmentVisible` function.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me.
The following however works like a charm:-

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean)
```

Comment: It's deprecated now! No use

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you have only one `Fragment`

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    //TODO: Your Code Here
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getUserVisibleHint` is now deprecated, and I was having problems with `isVisible` being true when another fragment was `add`ed in front of it. This detects the fragment's visibility on the back stack using its view. This may be helpful if your issue is related to other fragments on the back stack.

View extension to detect if a view is being displayed on the screen: (see also [How can you tell if a View is visible on screen in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039454/how-can-you-tell-if-a-view-is-visible-on-screen-in-android))

```
fun View.isVisibleOnScreen(): Boolean {
    if (!isShown) return false
    val actualPosition = Rect().also { getGlobalVisibleRect(it) }
    val screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val screen = Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
    return Rect.intersects(actualPosition, screen)
}
```

Then defined a back stack listener from the fragment, watching the top fragment on the stack (the one added last)

```
fun Fragment.setOnFragmentStackVisibilityListener(onVisible: () -> Unit) {
    val renderDelayMillis = 300L
    parentFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            if (isAdded) {
                val topStackFragment = parentFragmentManager.fragments[parentFragmentManager.fragments.size - 1]
                if (topStackFragment.view == view && isVisible && view!!.isVisibleOnScreen()) {
                    onVisible.invoke()
                }
            }
        }, renderDelayMillis)
    }
}
```

The back stack listener is called before the view is ready so an arbitrarily small delay was needed. The lambda is called when the view becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

## **In Kotlin**

if you use `FragmentPagerAdapter` and since `getUserVisibleHint()` is deprecated in api 29, I suggest you to add behaviour parameter `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` in your FragmentPagerAdapter like this:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
```

then in your fragment you can check using their lifecycle state:

```
if(lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
  // do something when fragment is visible
}
```