# Nested fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment, fragment-lifecycle

I have 4 fragments. I switch among them by using `hide`/`show` transactions. One of them may have nested fragments which are added by `replace` transaction. The issue is that if I add a nested fragment hide main fragment and show it again the `onHiddenChanged` method of my nested fragment is not called. Why so? How can I determine when my nested fragment become visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also came across the problem you are facing.

I found that hiding/showing a parent fragment had no effect on the child fragments' visible states, and wouldn't call `onHiddenChanged()` and would return `isVisible() = true` always.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652095/how-to-know-if-a-fragment-is-visible/24164840#24164840) in another question for my workaround.

Basically I created my own `getIsVisible()` function on a `BaseFragment` which recursively looks through any parents to find it's actual visible state. I am sure you could do something similar with `onHiddenChanged()` by propagating it to all the child fragments.

I know this is old, but maybe someone could benefit from this knowledge :)

Answer (score -4):

For inner fragments, use getChildFragmentManager().

---

Comment: And where is the answer here?