# How to avoid double selection on a RecyclerView OnClickListener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have a list using RecyclerView and a OnClickListener to handle the item clicks.

I used the same solution from:
[Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? And how RecyclerView is different from Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24885223/695443)

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // start a new fragment
    }

}
```

The problem is that if I quickly select two items, it will execute the onClick() two times and on this case, starting two new fragments.

Am I doing something wrong? What is the best approach to avoid this? Is a simple boolean flag enough for all the cases?

UPDATE:
This is a "pack selection screen", which you will select which pack you want to play. Then it will show a new fragment with all the puzzles from the selected pack.

Thanks!

Comment: its seems the right behaviour to me... which fragment do you whish to be displayed of the two

Comment: it doesn't matter which one (maybe the first one), i just don't want to open two fragments

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right about the `onClick`. Try this:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(fragment is playing) {
            return;
        }
        // start a new fragment
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand the if statement, can you explain better?

Comment: @thiagolr , if your target fragment is visible, you should not show it again. see this: [how-to-know-if-a-fragment-is-visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652095/how-to-know-if-a-fragment-is-visible).