# ViewPager and Fragment lifecycle with Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

I'm using an `Activity` which has a `ViewPager` holding 2 fragments, the pager handler is some implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

As I understand, pager adapter handles the lifecycle of the fragments inside it.

- I found out that my Activity `onResume()` method already gets called but the fragment `onStart()` method didn't even started.
  how in the world can I fix that? it destroy the whole point of lifecycle interactions between activity an fragments...
- Since pager adapter handles the lifecycle of the `Fragment`, does this means I can no longer depend on interaction with the `Activity`? I mean, if I want the `Activity` to do something in the `onResume()` but after the `Fragment` `onStart()` is called, I just can't do it...

**Edited:**

To make things clear:
Google says lifecycle of activity and fragment are going together, once one gets called, the other also gets called, e.g

1. `Activiy` -> `onCreate()` , and then, `Fragment` -> `onCreate()`
2. `Activiy` -> `onResume()` , and then, `Fragment` -> `onResume()`

BUT! in my case I get:
`Activity` -> `onCreate()` -> `onStart()` -> `onResume()` -> `onPostResume()`

And then:
`Fragment` -> `onAttach()` -> `onCreateView()` -> ... ->`onResume()`.

and to be clear, I am using a pager adapter (not "state" pager) and I have an abstract base activiy in my app which all activities should extend.

```
public abstract class AbsLoginAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.............
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "*******************onCreate");
    //do some general stuff like check for updates on server
}
```

**And in my extend activity:**

```
public class A extends AbsLoginAppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(TAG, "*******************onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    //also set pager + adapter + give it getSupportFragmentManager()
}
```

I am using:

**android.support.v4.view.ViewPager**

**android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter**

**android.support.v4.app.Fragment**

**android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity** (for abs activity)

Comment: post your code. cannot diagnose what we cannot see.

Comment: by the way, the adapter does not handle lifecycle of fragments. It does usually create them when necessary though via the getFragment() method.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're looking for in an answer...

Comment: well, the question is simple, Actvity onCreate + onStart + on Resume + onPostResume gets called, and only after those finished, the Fragment onAttach + onCreateView + ....... + onResume etc. gets called. so what am I missing? when Activity onStart gets called, then the Fragment onStart also need to get called, and then when onResume get called, also Fragment onResume need to get called..... i am using FragmentPagerAdapter and not "state" adapter

Comment: If you want to do something in the onResume() (in Activity) but after Fragment's onStart() is called, you can call getActivity() from your Fragment (in onResume() method), cast it to your concrete Activity and invoke any method from your Activity.

Answer (score 2):

The `Fragment[State]PagerAdapter` uses the activities `FragmentManager` - or in case of a nested `ViewPager` in a parent fragment - that fragment's child `FragmentManager` to manage the fragments, just like normal fragments would do. Really, the only thing that these adapter implementations do is that they hide the nasty `FragmentTransaction` stuff for you.

I had never problems that particular lifecycle callbacks weren't called for me in my fragments, so I cannot say anything about that. One thing however that is important to understand and that many people get wrong is that the adapter's `getItem()` method is called only when a fragment is freshly created; if it is restored from a saved state this method is not called again and people tend to do all fancy things there to initialize their just "created" fragment, while they should really look into `instantiateItem()`, which either returns the instance you give the adapter via `getItem()` or returns the reference of the fragment that was automatically re-created for you.

Another thing that is good to know about fragments in pager is the method `setUserVisibleHint(boolean)`. Since fragments are usually recreated and resumed all at once (non-state adapter) or on demand (state adapter), its usually important to know when one instance is actually visible to the user. This can be achieved by overriding the aforementioned method in a custom fragment.

Comment: my answer above explain better what I meant.

Comment: I think the answer hide somewhere in the FragmentPagerAdapter, because FragmentPagerAdapter is acting as fragment manager , which I guess it creates the pages (fragments) as it wants. but if this is the case, what's the point of using it, if it break all the lifecycle!?