# Android check there is no fragment showing

Tags: android, android-fragments

hello I am having an activity which have like 10 fragments I want to check when there is no fragment visible i.e after pressing  back button I return to the main activity `I want catch this back not back between fragments` 
where no fragment visible 
I found a way here
[How to know if a Fragment is Visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652095/how-to-know-if-a-fragment-is-visible)
 to check by tag name like here but I can't check for all 10 fragments by tag name
any help?

Comment: if you found this - getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0 means not fragment is currently visible.

Comment: thanks a lot it works with getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==0 as I extends activity

Comment: For Kotlin, you can use supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question right, by using

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.some_layout_id) != null)
```

you can find out if the layout with that id contains a fragment or not.
This way you don't need to check for each fragment and you can check the fragment container directly. I hope it helps!

Comment: this works too  with  getFragmentManager() though thank you .