# How to check if fragment is visible in fragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have `FragmentActivity` and there are 4 fragments inside. `LoginFragment, RegistrationFragment, ForgottenPasswordFragment, LocalityFragment`.

User can switch between them by back button, but if you push `back button` in default fragment (`LoginFragment` or `LocalityFragment`) I want to disable it, because it will return user to the `SplashScreen`.

So I've found some method how to get currently displayed fragment. I've tried `fragment.userVisibleHint` and `fragment.isVisible`. Both of them are returning false as I push back button even if that fragment is currently displayed on screen.

Code:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        val activeLoginFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("LOGIN_FRAGMENT") as LoginFragment?
        val activeLocalityFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("LOCALITY_FRAGMENT") as LocalityPickFragment?

        createLog("onBackPressedLogin ", activeLoginFragment.toString())
        createLog("onBackPressedLogin ", "LoginFragment is: " + activeLoginFragment?.userVisibleHint)
        if ( (activeLoginFragment == null || !activeLoginFragment.userVisibleHint) || (activeLocalityFragment == null || !activeLocalityFragment.userVisibleHint) ){
            createLog("onBackPressedLogin ", "not visible")
            super.onBackPressed()
        }

    }

fun switchToForgottenPasswordFragment(){
        val mPendingRunnable = Runnable {
            fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.apply {
                replace(R.id.startup_fragment_container, forgottenPasswordFragment)
                addToBackStack(null)
                commit()
            }
        }

        val fragmentThread = Thread(mPendingRunnable)
        fragmentThread.start()
    }
```

Comment: use `findFragmentById` method with your fragment container id and check for it's instance.

Comment: And how do I know each fragment's ID? Or instance of FragmentClassName?

Comment: How are you inflating your fragments?

Comment: I create instance of each fragment in onCreate and then I just switching these instances by function. (Added to my post).

Comment: I mean are you using `FrameLayout` to inflate dynamically or using `fragment` tag in xml?

Comment: Yep I have frameLayout (startup_fragment_container) in function

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646615/5647037) Basically the same as @JeelVankhede said already.

Comment: So I should do something like this: val activeFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.startup_fragment_container) 

if activeFragment is LoginFragment: do something

Comment: Yes, exactly like that, check if the fragment is an instance of the type you care about. Also an unrelated note, you should FINISH your splash screen, so it's not even possible for the user to get to it. It's kinda bad if they do in any way.

Comment: Could you provide the code you use to add the fragments?