# Update data in fragment with getting push notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

This is not a duplicate question. So please don't make this question as a duplicate.

I have scenario. I am implementing chat module in which all functionalities i have already done.

> MainActivity - MainFragment - Chat List Fragment.

`MainActivity` holds the `MainFragment` which have a viewpager with tablayout. `MainFragment's` view pager adapter holds `ChatList` Fragment in which API call for chat list.

Now if i already in chat list fragment and push notification come for message then notification should not be appeared that i did. But i want to update data in chat list means want to call chat list API.

I am not getting `MainActivity` context so i can access `MainFragment` and retrieve that `ChatList` fragment.

**Code**

```
 case "chat_message":




//                if (HirerTabsActivity.isOpenChat()) {
//                    Log.v("ATATATA", "asd");
//
//                } else {

                if (GetUserProfileData.getInstance().getUserDetail().getUser_type().equalsIgnoreCase("artist")) {
                    intent = new Intent(this, ArtistTabsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("fromNotification", "Y");

                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(this, HirerTabsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("fromNotification", "Y");
                }


            break;
```

**Updated Code**

```
case "chat_message":

            if (mediaPrefs.getString(Constant.SharedPreferences_IN_CHAT_SCREEN, "").equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                sendBroadcast(new Intent().setAction("chat_refresh"));
            } else {

                if (GetUserProfileData.getInstance().getUserDetail().getUser_type().equalsIgnoreCase("artist")) {
                    intent = new Intent(this, ArtistTabsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("fromNotification", "Y");

                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(this, HirerTabsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("fromNotification", "Y");
                }
            }
```

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Comment: use a local broadcast receiver and fire a broadcast event whenever the notification appears.

Comment: But how can i come to know that i m already in chat screen. Because for that i don't want show notificaiton

Comment: Use `ActivityManager`

Comment: @PiyusGupta Or a hacky way is to save your state in SharedPreference. and in ViewPager onPageChangeListener clear that value

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LocalBroadcastManager: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager

With this you can send a local broadcast from your Service listening for pushes to your Activity/Fragment.
You can find an example implementation here:
[How to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Comment: But i want to know that I am in current fragment.

Comment: You can use this to see if your fragment is visible or not:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652095/how-to-know-if-a-fragment-is-visible/16653927
Do this in your broadcastreceiver in your fragment

Answer (score 0):

good Question lets share my way how it works.

in Notficationservice you nee to send broadcast

```
 //refresh chat list 
 sendBroadcast(new Intent().setAction("chat_refresh"));
```

and at your fragment

```
 private class RefreshBrodcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (getUserVisibleHint() && isVisible()) {
               // your can refresh via api
            }
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to show a notification at when you are on chat fragment  then you can manage  Static flag or Preference flag with `onresume() & onpause()`  method

Comment: Okay. But suppose if i m not in chat screen then ??

Comment: if your flag false at your notification service class put if else condition  i just edit last two line please check @PiyushGupta

Comment: @PiyushGupta  at top of Notificationservice class you just put a condition that if flag true (either from preference or static variable) then show noti  otherwise fire broadcast thats very simple way if you understand

Comment: Check my updated code again. In onResume set Flag "Y" and in onPause set "N" in CHat list fragment.@Vishal Patel

Comment: For that you have to understand Broadcast manager properly + have to debug that flow.

Comment: I have debug that too  though not working. Also used Event Bus but i m not getting that too.