# My value event listener is not being removed properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat system in my app. When the user who is on the receiving end of the message sees the message the isSeen node gets updated from false to true. When I don't open the ChatFragment the messages doesn't get updated for the receiver but once I open it the messages get updated to isSeen true.

My problem is when I leave the chat fragment and someone sends a message the node isSeen automatically gets updated to true even though I am not inside of the chat fragment that displays the messages between the two users. I have narrowed the problem down and found that when I remove this method `private void addSeenEventListener()` nothing gets updated and when I add it back the updating doesn't stop. Like the value event listener keeps on running.

ChatFragment.java:

```
private void showMessages() {

        DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = RootRef.child("Messages").child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID);
        userMessageKeyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                messagesList.clear(); // Clear the list before adding new messages

                for (DataSnapshot conversationSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : conversationSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                        if (messageSnapshot != null) {

                            Messages messages = new Messages();
                            String strMessage = messageSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                            String strFrom = messageSnapshot.child("from").getValue().toString();
                            String strType = messageSnapshot.child("type").getValue().toString();
                            String strDate = messageSnapshot.child("date_time").getValue().toString();
                            String strImgURL = ""; // Initialize imageUrl as empty string

                            // Check if imageUrl field exists and is not null
                            if (messageSnapshot.hasChild("imgURL") && messageSnapshot.child("imgURL").getValue() != null) {
                                strImgURL = messageSnapshot.child("imgURL").getValue().toString();
                            }

                            messages.setMessage(strMessage);
                            messages.setFrom(strFrom);
                            messages.setType(strType);
                            messages.setMessageDate(strDate);
                            messages.setImgURL(strImgURL); // Set imageUrl
                            messagesList.add(messages);

                            if (!strFrom.equals(messageSenderID)) {
                                // The current user is the receiver, so add the event listener
                                //addSeenEventListener();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getContext(), messagesList, messageSenderID, messageReceiverID);
                userMessagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

                addSeenEventListener();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

---

```
private void addSeenEventListener() {

    if (getContext() != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Seen event listener.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (!isActivityPaused) {
        // Add the event listener only when the activity is not paused
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            DatabaseReference messagesRef = RootRef.child("Messages").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

            seenListener = messagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Iterate through messages and mark them as seen when they are viewed
                    // Your logic here
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot conversationSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (!conversationSnapshot.getKey().equals("conversationId")) {
                                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : conversationSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Messages message = messageSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                                    if (message != null && message.getTo() != null && message.getTo().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && !message.getIsSeen()) {
                                        //messageSnapshot.getRef().child("isSeen").setValue(true);

                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Users: " + message.getTo() + " " + firebaseUser.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    // Handle onCancelled event
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void stopSeenEventListener() {
    // Remove the seen event listener when the fragment is paused or stopped
    if (seenListener != null) {
        DatabaseReference messageRef = RootRef.child("Messages");
        messageRef.removeEventListener(seenListener);
    }

    if (seenListener != null && RootRef != null) {
        RootRef.removeEventListener(seenListener);
        seenListener = null; // Optionally reset the listener
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Start the seen event listener when the fragment is resumed
    //startSeenEventListener();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Stop the seen event listener when the fragment is paused
    stopSeenEventListener();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (RootRef != null && seenListener != null) {
        RootRef.removeEventListener(seenListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, if the fragment is visible run that event listener, or I maybe wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16652217/175554 that may help on that

Comment: @ozkanpakdil I tried that but it didn't help.