# Fragment's onResume() not called when popped from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

Hi I am developing android application in which I am using I am using single `Activity` and 3 fragments. So consider I have 3 fragments A B C. When I switch from A to B, I am adding `Fragment` to backstack and simillar for B to C. Now when I click back from C it shows me B and similar for B to A as well.

But thing is that when I come from C to B or B to A, it's not calling `onResume()` or any other life cycle methods of `Fragment`.

What I want to do actually for every `Fragment` I have different title in `ActionBar`. So, in my code, when I move from A to B or B to c, I am changing activity title inside fragment. But when I click on back it not changing according to that.

What is the actual problem? Why after pop from backstack its not calling `onResume()` for my `Fragment`? How do I solve this problem? Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: onResume() of the fragment is called only when the activity is resumed. So this wont help you. Even I'm facing similar issue right now. You can implement `OnBackStackChangedListener` and get the fragment name in the top of the stack and set the actionbar title based on that.

Answer (score 26):

`onResume()` of the `Fragment` is called only when the `Activity` is resumed. So this wont help you. Even I'm facing similar issue right now. You can implement `OnBackStackChangedListener` and get the fragment name in the top of the stack and set the `ActionBar` title based on that.

```
private FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener getListener()
{
    FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener result = new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener()
    {
        public void onBackStackChanged()
        {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

            if (manager != null)
            {
                if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() >= 1){
                    String topOnStack = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(manager.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName();
                    Log.i("TOP ON BACK STACK",topOnStack);
                }
                }
            }
    };

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm using too

Answer (score 16):

Try to use the `replace` method instead `add` on the `FragmentTransaction`. This work for me:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: This works. Probably should now be the accepted answer.

Comment: The fragments <b>onResume()</b> or onPause() will be called only when the Activities onResume() or onPause() is called. They are tightly coupled to the Activity. if you call replace onStop() will called.

Comment: Replacing the fragment will recreate the UI and execute the business logic written in onCreateView and onViewCreated methods. Be careful before using this approach.

Answer (score 9):

As others have said already, `onResume()` is only called when the activity itself is resumed, so that isn't going to help at all.

You need to check if you're adding a new fragment, or replacing an existing fragment in your fragment transaction:

- If you `replace()` a previous fragment, that previous fragment will be recreated from scratch when you go back to it, so `onCreateView()` will be called again, and you can update your toolbar title there. You probably do already.
- If you `add()` a new fragment, the previous fragment is still there, only not visible. When you go back to it, it's up to you to get the last entry from the back stack (use `getBackStackEntryCount()` and `getBackStackEntryAt()` in the fragment manager), get the corresponding Fragment object (use `findFragmentByTag()` in the fragment manager), cast that Fragment to some base class that all your fragments will inherit from, and call a custom method, e.g. `onVisible()`, on that fragment. The default implementation of `onVisible()` in your base class does nothing. Override in each fragment to update toolbar title, FAB, and anything else as required. I'm also calling `onVisible()` from `onResume()` to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this method of fragment :

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
}
```

Comment: But when I pop up fragment from stack then it's not calling this.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your fragment.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        if (visible && isResumed()) {
            onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!getUserVisibleHint()) {
            return;
        }
        setData();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this way, add this block code in your fragment

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
            val fm = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            fm?.let {
                if (it.backStackEntryCount == YOUR_FRAGMENT_BACK_STACK_INDEX) {
                    // your fragment visible
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the Best answer. Trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers relied on a particular fragment transaction being named, or having a tagged fragment, relying on a deprecated method, or putting logic in the Activity.  This detects the fragment's visibility on the back stack using its view, which for my needs this was close enough to an `onResume`. Since this is concerned with being on top of the back stack.

View extension to detect if a view is being displayed on the screen: (see also [How can you tell if a View is visible on screen in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039454/how-can-you-tell-if-a-view-is-visible-on-screen-in-android))

```
fun View.isVisibleOnScreen(): Boolean {
    if (!isShown) return false
    val actualPosition = Rect().also { getGlobalVisibleRect(it) }
    val screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val screen = Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
    return Rect.intersects(actualPosition, screen)
}
```

Then defined a back stack listener from the fragment, watching the top fragment on the stack (the one added last)

```
fun Fragment.setOnFragmentStackVisibilityListener(onVisible: () -> Unit) {
    val renderDelayMillis = 300L
    parentFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            if (isAdded) {
                val topStackFragment = parentFragmentManager.fragments[parentFragmentManager.fragments.size - 1]
                if (topStackFragment.view == view && isVisible && view!!.isVisibleOnScreen()) {
                    onVisible.invoke()
                }
            }
        }, renderDelayMillis)
    }
}
```

The back stack listener is called before the view is ready so an arbitrarily small delay was needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change title on `onCreateView()` of Fragment.

Comment: But when I pop up fragment from stack then it's not calling any life cycle method. Then what should I. thank you for help.

Comment: You need to change the title in onCreateView method of fragment. When you pop or add fragment to stack oncreateview method is called and then you set title according to your fragment class.

Comment: @HarshitRathi I tried this and as @nilkash said `onCreateView()` is not called when a fragment is popped from teh back stack and the new one becomes visible.