# How to get view visibility by it's resource view id

Tags: android

is there a way to get the View on the screen if it's visible or not giving the resource id for example if i have a button id in the xml is "@id/save"

passing "save" id can we get if the view is currently visible or not from any where in the app.

Answer (score 2):

```
findViewById(R.id.save).isShown()
```

> from any where in the app

Finding any view only makes sense for a single activity/fragment/dialog/ViewGroup. You can reuse the same view id across multiple screens to represent completely different view types.

I'm not sure it makes sense to know if a button is visible for a screen that doesn't have the view, so you'll need to add a null check to the above line.

If you want to put your button in some dialog box, then you would check if the dialog is present

Comment: That's a good start but it won't check whether the view has been scrolled off the screen. Also, what about the "from any where in the app" part of OP's question?

Comment: For scrolling, probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039454/how-can-you-tell-if-a-view-is-visible-on-screen-in-android