# Android google-play-liked listview

Tags: android, android-listview, google-play, scrollview

Im new to android and practicing with an UI like googleplay apps, this is default view of the list : 
[image]

when i scroll the list view up , the action bar got scrolled up and disappeared , basically my English is too bad and i dont know how or which keyword i must use in google search to get the result like this (as you see it looks like the action bar is inside the listview  ) 
[image]

please show me how or give me an example to learn, thank you !

Comment: Guess it is a gridview...

Comment: I think it is GridView with material design : http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-principles

Comment: Basically You are/He is asking about the actionbar's hiding on scroll up the view, but not the Gridview itself. For an instance sample (before Lolipop), you should have a look at this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-maximize-android-screen-real-estate-by-showing-and-hiding-the-action-bar/

From Lolipop, Android introduce new RecycleView (which, i guess, is the GridView here), and the new ToolBar which is playing the roll of the so-called Action Bar. You may want to try to search about using it first! Cheer Vietnamese Developer!

Comment: I found a more-helpful URL for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655448/android-lollipop-toolbar-scolling

Comment: Thank you all especially @Nguyễn Hoài Nam you are totally right, may i have your contact , just for exchanging exp . thanks again

Comment: You can email me here: 8x8BJm5ueQh3@meltmail.com
This is a temporary email, will be automatically deleted after 3 hours :).

Answer (score 0):

you can define your layout structure like following :

```
<FrameLayout>

    <GridView or RecyclerView/>

    <MenuBar id="menuBar2" visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

to making the grid be able to scroll with the TitleBar and MenuBar, we should add a Header with GridView, of course RecyclerView would be easier to do this than GridView. the Header layout's structure would be like this :

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">

    <TitleBar/>

    <MenuBar id="menuBar1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Once the `menuBar1` fully scroll off to invisible, display the `menuBar2`, also synchronizing the menu state between both. The menuBar2 will appearing on top of that LinearLayout. when user scrolling to top and the menuBar1 just visible, hide the menuBar2.

how to determine if a View is fully invisible? the [View.getLocalVisibleRect()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428208/1294681) would tell for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check [How do the animation hiding the ActionBar and keeping tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931122/how-do-the-animation-hiding-the-actionbar-and-keeping-tabs)

It suggests that you use https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView.