# How to find is button reachable for user or no

Tags: android, android-layout, button, scroll

Simple question but I can't find solution.

**Default data:** I have some `Button` among other buttons. Buttons are in the `LinearLayout` and then in the `ScrollView`.

**Situation:** ScrollView was scrolled, button is not on those part of screen which user can see now.

StackO suggests me only `getVisibility()` method, but programmatically button is visible!

How can I understand see user button or no - is button on the visible part of the screen for user or no?

Comment: I guess the solution for your question is the third answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791607/how-can-i-check-if-a-view-is-visible-or-not-in-android

Comment: @OrestShemeliuk, yes you are right